# cakephp model association (view)

Tags: cakephp

In cakephp I have codesets and codesetitems. codesetitems belong to codesets so in my codesetitems I have belongsTo = 'Codeset'. But in my view I don't seem to be able to call $codeset['Codesetitem']['id']. It says undefined index Codesetitem. I already checked out the cake documentation. One codeset can have many codesetitems.

Comment: Is your CodesetController passing a properly constructed $codeset array that in fact contains Codesetitem objects? You could $this->log($codeset) in the controller then look for the output in the PHP error file. If you are using a traditional web page, I reckon a debug() statement will print the output in HTML.

Comment: How are you a) retrieving the data, and b) sending it to the view?

Answer (score 0):

Explanation about how `cakephp` handle and output array of result.

In order to get associated result you must define it in each model as below.

**CodesetItem Model**

```
<?php
class CodesetItem extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'CodesetItem';

    var $belongsTo = array
    (
        'Codeset' => array
        (
            'className' => 'Codeset',
            'foreignKey' => 'codeset_id',
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => ''
        )
    );
}
?>
```

**Codeset Model**

```
<?php
class Codeset extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Codeset';

    var $hasMany = array
    (
        'CodesetItem' => array
        (
            'className' => 'CodesetItem',
            'foreignKey' => 'codeset_id',
            'dependent' => false,
            'conditions' => '',
            'fields' => '',
            'order' => '',
            'limit' => '',
            'offset' => '',
            'exclusive' => '',
            'finderQuery' => '',
            'counterQuery' => ''
        )
    );
}
?>
```

**Codeset Controller**

```
<?php
class CodesetsController extends AppController
{
    var $name = 'Codesets';

    function beforeFilter()
    {
        parent::beforeFilter();
    }

    function index()
    {
        $codesets = $this->Codeset->find('first');
        pr($codesets);
        exit;
    }
}
?>
```

Above will out put array of codeset with index of 0 means as below

```
Array
(
    [Codeset] => Array
    (
        [id] => 121
        [name] => Gwoo the Kungwoo
        [created] => 2007-05-01 10:31:01
    )
    [CodesetItem] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 123
                [codeset_id] => 121
                [title] => On Gwoo the Kungwoo
                [body] => The Kungwooness is not so Gwooish
                [created] => 2006-05-01 10:31:01
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 124
                [codeset_id] => 123
                [title] => More on Gwoo
                [body] => But what of the ‘Nut?
                [created] => 2006-05-01 10:41:01
            )
    )
)
```

but when you use find('all') in find method it will out as below.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [Codeset] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121
            [name] => Gwoo the Kungwoo
            [created] => 2007-05-01 10:31:01
        )
        [CodesetItem] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 123
                    [codeset_id] => 121
                    [title] => On Gwoo the Kungwoo
                    [body] => The Kungwooness is not so Gwooish
                    [created] => 2006-05-01 10:31:01
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 124
                    [codeset_id] => 121
                    [title] => More on Gwoo
                    [body] => But what of the ‘Nut?
                    [created] => 2006-05-01 10:41:01
                )
        )
    )
    [1] => Array
    (
        [Codeset] => Array
        (
            [id] => 121
            [name] => Gwoo the Kungwoo
            [created] => 2007-05-01 10:31:01
        )
        [CodesetItem] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 123
                    [codeset_id] => 121
                    [title] => On Gwoo the Kungwoo
                    [body] => The Kungwooness is not so Gwooish
                    [created] => 2006-05-01 10:31:01
                )
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 124
                    [codeset_id] => 121
                    [title] => More on Gwoo
                    [body] => But what of the ‘Nut?
                    [created] => 2006-05-01 10:41:01
                )
        )
    )
)
```